# Reindex a file in alfresco 5.0

Tags: alfresco, solr4, alfresco-webscripts

I just want to re-indexed a file,I am using this api "https://localhost:8443/solr4/admin/cores?action=REINDEX&nodeid=983" 
but i could not re-indexed.Can any one tell how can i re-indexed a file ?
I am using alfresco 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the count of error nodes using your admin console and confirm that something really is in error.

The action you mentioned is the right one (there are a few more, check the official documentation), but if the node is not reindexed, the action obviously fails.

I suggest you raise the SOLR log level and find out more.

In my experience, when something like this happens it almost always has to do with JSON parsing. Check out this tutorial, maybe it will bring you closer to the solution.

http://alfresco.blog.redpill-linpro.com/2015/04/30/how-to-debug-solr-exceptionswarnings-for-alfresco-part-2/