# Find reason why a file fails to get indexed?

Tags: solr4, alfresco-webscripts

How to find a reason why a file failed to get indexed in Alfresco?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the previous replies...

If nodes fail to index you can see why.
Use the SOLR admin pages and schema browser. For example see here:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr4/#/alfresco/schema-browser?field=EXCEPTIONMESSAGE
```

and click load term info. No terms ==> no problems.

Also see:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr4/#/alfresco/schema-browser?field=EXCEPTIONSTACK
```

These fields should have been stored (they were in the past and will be in the future...). If you feel adventurous, you could fix these fields to be stored in schema.xml. Next time you will be able to get the failure related to a particular node via stored fields - add "&fl=*" to the solr query URL to get all stored fields in the results.

Unindexed nodes are unindexed for a reason not an error.
The nodes will most likely have an aspect and properties that say they are unindexed. For example, some share site related configuration is unindexed.

You may find an underlying cause for an indexing error in the Alfresco logs as well as in the index fields. The index fields are more useful if something went wrong on the SOLR side.

You can try to fix the nodes using:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr4/admin/cores?action=RETRY
```

This will give them another go ....

It is also possible a file has metadata indexed but fails to transform its content into text. This will show up in the Alfresco logs. You can see how content transformation did looking at

```
http://localhost:8080/solr4/#/alfresco/schema-browser?field=content@s__tr_status@{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}content
```

Hit the Load term info button. You should mostly see "ok" and "no_transform"

Comment: Hi Andy i am using isindexed and iscontentindexed property to identify the unindexed file in alfresco solr but its not giving corrrect value can u tell me this is effective or not to use?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Unindexed Solr Transactions](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/solr-unindex.html)

> You can check the status of the Solr index to identify the nodes to a transaction that failed to index.

Please see [Troubleshooting Solr Index](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/solr-index-fix.html)

> Use this information to repair a transaction that failed to index.

Comment: thanks to answer  can u tell me one more thing how to find out transaction_id and acltx_id bcoz i just find the nodes those are unindexed and i want one more thing why they are unindexed i mean reason behind that bcoz in Unindexed Solr Transactions its not giving description

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

[Reindex a file in alfresco 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053720/reindex-a-file-in-alfresco-5-0/36084911#36084911)

Also, get familiar with:

https://localhost:8443/solr4/alfresco/afts?q=DOC_TYPE:ErrorNode
https://localhost:8443/solr4/alfresco/afts?q=DOC_TYPE:UnindexedNode

Good luck!

Comment: when i am using this api its giving 10 file but when i am using isIndexed property its giving 33 files is it possible or am i doing any mistake?